# How do you prevent hidden (overflow) elements from being rendered?

Tags: scroll, overflow, hidden, absolute

I have an absolute positioned div off the side of the page with just a bit sticking in. I have applied overflow: hidden to html and the parent div, which gets rid of the scroll bar, but people can still use the middle mouse button to move the page across.

Is there a way to prevent anything that overflows from actually being rendered on the page or simply prohibit middle mouse scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to set overwflow-x and overflow-y, like this:

```
.class {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

if it's not help add some !importanta to this style.